# Thread Input parameter

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, thread-safety

I want to run a class with different value in a thread list. like this :

```
     int index = 0;
     foreach (TreeNode nd in tvew.Nodes[0].Nodes)
     {
         threadping[index] = new Thread(delegate()
         { this.Invoke(new DelegateClientState(InvokeCheckNetworkState), new object[] {nd}); });

         threadping[index].Name = nd.Name;
         threadping[index].IsBackground = true;
         threadping[index].Start();

         index++;
     }
```

but when i debug the code, i see that the class parameter is just the last value. 
i mean when i go through thread class i see that each time that class run the value of the input parameter is the last value for the last thread.

Can anybody tell me WHY?

Comment: Can you show the code where you have initialized the threadPing collection. And what is "class parameter" or what thread class you are debugging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the nd variable is captured in a closure. When the threads run, they are all referencing the same TreeNode instance, namely the last one that was assigned to `nd`. To fix, use a separate variable that doesn't change within the scope:

```
 foreach (TreeNode nd in tvew.Nodes[0].Nodes)
 {
     var current = nd;
     threadping[index] = new Thread(delegate()
     { this.Invoke(new DelegateClientState(InvokeCheckNetworkState), new object[] {current}); });
```

If we get compiler-technical, this happens because the compiler generates an anonymous class containing your loop variable in order to make it accessible for the thread delegate. This is expected behaviour, although maybe a bit counter-intuitive when you run into it the first time.

For a longer explanation of closures and the capture of variables, [see the Captured Variables section here (bottom section) in a Jon Skeet article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/csharp2/delegates.html), or [this article from Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx). This is commonly known as an "access to modified closure" bug. If you search for the term on StackOverflow or Google, you will get a lot of hits explaining it.

Comment: tnx, it works. another question : why my threads does not work at the same time? i point the break point on the first line of the "InvokeCheckNetworkState" it raises when the first loop finish. it's like the threads wait for the previous thread finish. i mean thy dont work at the same time. What should i do?